# How to build database for variant management in a webshop

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, webshop

I am searching for a guideline on how to set up my database for a auction side.

My problem is, that there is a lot of different product types - let's say paintings, clothes, computers etc. They have different specifications, and it should be possible to set just Product A in size L on auction - or the whole stock of Product B e.g.

How should I build my database for optimal performance - and coding - in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following database/object structure:

```
[Auction] n..1 [Category] 1..n [Variation Attribute] 1..n [Attribute Value]
```

An auction then has a category and several attribute values referring the variation attribute as well:

```
[Auction] = [Category], [Name], [Description]
[Auction_AttrVal] = [AuctionID], [VarAttrID], [AttrValID]
```

First of all you can have some kind of category table, which holds items like "Paintings", "Clothes", "Computers". An auction / product is assigned to one category.

Each category then defines variation attributes for this specific category. An example would be "Size" for the category "Clothes" or "CPU" for the category "Computers". You can also add predefined values for the variation attributes to limit the number of variations and avoid differentiations like "3GhZ" vs "3 GhZ".

This mechanism also allows for easy filtering of search results. You select a category and simply load all variation attributes as filters (or add a flag to an attribute to declare it as such) and offer the values for filtering to the end-user.

Furthermore you can make variation attributes for a category mandatory to force users who create the auctions (I'm assuming it's Consumer-to-Consumer) to provide sufficient information for their auction.

The code will probably be quite generic and simple. The database structure is highly flexible and extensible. Performance is much better than having all in one table. You probably should create an index (for the field `AuctionID`) for the `Auction_AttrVal` table. Please let me know if the database structure is not explained properly.

Comment: I have the problem, that under "categories" there can be both e.g. t-shirts and jeans which should have different sizes. Maybe this could be solved by children categories, but isn't it possible to make the differentiations variable for each product but still in some way "connected" to the other to make a trimmed and nice way of the calues (your "3GhZ" vs "3 GhZ" is exactly a thing I will avoid)

Comment: You can make parent categories. You assign the auction to the lowest category level (e.g. if you have "Clothes" as parent and "Jeans" as subcategory you assign to "Jeans", which implies the assignment to "Clothes"). Each level can define different variation attributes. When you create the auction you simply move up the hierarchy and add all attributes. This would also allow you to override attributes of the parent by giving it the same name and then on the way up the hierarchy check if the attribute was already mentioned. Simply add a ParentCategoryID (which can be null) to the Category table.

Comment: To be more specific about the overriding: let's say Clothes define a size (XXL, XL, L, M, S, XS). Jeans however measure in 32/32, 34/32, ... You define the variation attribute "Size" for "Clothes" with values (XXL, XL, ...) and for Jeans with different values (32/32, ...). When you define the options for the user, you find "Size" for "Jeans" first and add it as parameter. Then when you encounter "Size" again for "Clothes" you simply ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, but this will give some limitations with different prices. E.g. iPod 16 gb, 32 gb and 64 gb? Am I right?

Comment: I know it should be auctions - but there should in the auction be mentioned a "normal price" from the product variation - so the price of the variations should be able to change..

Comment: If it's a price determining variation the best practice is to create multiple auctions for each attribute value with different prices. Else you have 2 or 3 price-determining attributes and how are you going to determine a price then. You could have a +10% or +10$/€/... on the price for a variation attribute value, but this would probably not be flexible enough, since the price add-on for an iPod would probably be bigger than for a Sony MP3 player - and that's why you need different auctions/products in this case. You could link these different iPods to one master iPod product though.

Comment: But what about making e.g. a combination table saying "iPod 32 GB red" => price: £10 and "iPod 32 GB blue" => price: £9

This is in a "combinations"-table holding description and price. Then you have a Many:many table holding e.g. SpecificationID and VariationID

This means that in Variations you are have both "32 GB" and "White" as specifications for the product. And therefore you make a row in the table connecting the "32 GB" and "White" to the combination of "iPod 32 GB White" with the price of £10?